# Check that a mathematical operation (adding, multiplying) can be done successfully in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given a specific group of "Strings" that represent integers in an addition operation, how is it possible to know if the calculation is possible in javascript? for instance.

`2 + 2` (definetly possible)

`20000000000000000 - 1` (not possible)

`2e50 + 2e60` (not possible)

`200000 + 5 + 40 + 300 + 2000 + 10000` (possible)

The same applies to multiplication, several integers, duable or not?

`2*2` (possible)

`3*2e200` (possible)

`4*-3e700` (not possible)

Comment: eval("1+1")? Im not shure if it is that simple...

Comment: There is no simply answer. What kind of problem are you solving?

Comment: Javascript is a well developed scripting language. So technically , every calculation is possible,  just it will not come to a correct solution if your approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
Open your browsers error console and view what this does.

```
"use strict";
var i,
    numbers=[
        2+2,
        20000000000000000 - 1,
        2e50 + 2e60,
        200000 + 5 + 40 + 300 + 2000 + 10000,
        2*2,
        3*2e200,
        4*-3e700
    ],
    s=numbers.length;
for(i=0;i<s;i++){
    console.log(
        'The value of array index '+i+' is'+
        ((Number.isSafeInteger((numbers[i])))?'':' NOT')+
        ' Safe'
    );
}
```

Output from console:

```
The value of array index 0 is Safe
The value of array index 1 is NOT Safe
The value of array index 2 is NOT Safe
The value of array index 3 is Safe
The value of array index 4 is Safe
The value of array index 5 is NOT Safe
The value of array index 6 is NOT Safe
```

Some of these number may be accurate, but can not be compared to determine which is greater

Comment: Click on `<>` in editor and can run in *"stack snippet"* console built into this page

Comment: NoScript's XSS filter gives me issues there

Comment: Just hope you do not need IE support ;)

Comment: Well, `Number.isSafeInteger(2e200) === false` even though as stated by OP, `3*2e200 (possible)`

Comment: `javascript:void(alert(2e200*3===2e200*3-1))` it may be possible to calculate it but it is beyond the point of comparing in JavaScript, therefore we can not validate it's accuracy via JavaScirpt; It is not perfect but it is as close as we can get; well maybe if we send it to the server via AJAX we could